# Sage Pay Version 3 upgrade in Ecwid

Tags: shopping-cart, opayo

Has anyone got a clue as to how to upgrade Sage Pay to version 3 for an Ecwid shopping cart.

Initially we just had a plugin system with no access to change codes, so this leaves me clueless as to how to upgrade.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We know that SagePay will be updated in 5 months, so our developers are currently preparing a new Ecwid update which will include all the updates for SagePay.

So, you don’t need to do anything - all the work will be done on our side thanks to the SAAS nature of Ecwid.

Regards,

Ecwid Customer Care team.

Comment: Thanks, we have the same requirement. Just for info, SagePay are telling me that I need to upgrade to SagePay v3 before 31 July 2015, which is a bit less than the 5 months you quote.